# Pipe to allow multiple filter values simultaneously - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filter, pipe

Buttons are generated using `*ngFor` bringing back as many different types of values available to filter by. I'm filtering on a key of 'location', therefore if there are locations of 'west' and 'england' then two buttons of 'west' and 'england' are available to filter by.

What I want to be able to do is select more than one filter. If I click 'england' all the results for 'england' come back, then if I click 'west' then 'west' comes back as well as 'england' still being "active". Currently, I can only click one filter at a time.

I think I need to assign an active class to my button then this will push an array of whats active to send to my pipe to do the filtering... ?

**My filter Button**

```
  <div ngDefaultControl [(ngModel)]="filteredLocation" name="locationFilter" id="locationFilter">
    <button value="All" class="m-2 btn btn-primary" type="button">All</button>
    <button [class.active]="selectedIndex === i" (click)="filteredLocation = entry.location" class="m-2 btn btn-primary" type="button" *ngFor="let entry of timeLine | filterUnique; let i = index">{{entry.location}}</button>
  </div>
```

**single filter on results**

```
<div class="timeline">
  <my-timeline-entry *ngFor="let entry of timeLine | filter:filteredLocation:'location'" timeEntryHeader={{entry.year}} timeEntryContent={{entry.detail}} timeEntryPlace={{entry.place}} timeEntryLocation={{entry.location}}></my-timeline-entry>
</div>
```

I have created a stackBlitz of what I've got - try clicking on a filter you will see only one filter can be applied at one time. https://stackblitz.com/edit/timeline-angular-7-nve3zw

Any help here would be awesome. Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be using a pipe here since you are expecting the pipe to reference a property value by indexing (See [here](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be multiple ways to do that one would be to attach some property to determine if location is active for example `isLocationActive`

Then toggle this flag as per your need and to apply active class also you don't need filter pipe in that case

So your html will look like

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <div ngDefaultControl [(ngModel)]="filteredLocation" name="locationFilter" id="locationFilter">
        <button value="All" class="m-2 btn btn-primary" (click)="activeAllEntries()" type="button">All</button>
        <button [class.active]="entry.isLocationActive" (click)="entry.isLocationActive = !entry.isLocationActive" class="m-2 btn btn-primary" type="button" *ngFor="let entry of timeLine | filterUnique; let i = index">{{entry.location}}</button>
      </div>
</div>

<div class="timeline">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let entry of timeLine">
<my-timeline-entry *ngIf="entry.isLocationActive" timeEntryHeader={{entry.year}} timeEntryContent={{entry.detail}} timeEntryPlace={{entry.place}} timeEntryLocation={{entry.location}}></my-timeline-entry>
  </ng-container>

</div>
```

TS function

```
   activeAllEntries() {
      this.timeLine.forEach(t=> t.isLocationActive=!t.isLocationActive)
   }
```

[working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/timeline-angular-7-iczjk8)

Comment: Great, I will take a look at the code - pretty new to Angular so building up as much as possible. Thanks

Comment: @TomRudge glad to help you

Comment: I've found a small bug actually, the filter will only bring back one record e.g. there are two east but only one returns

Comment: Sry out of office can check tomorrow morning :)